# Destroy a juju service and also its associated machine

Tags: bash, juju

I'm looking for a way to automatically destroy the associated machine after destroying a service with:

```
juju destroy-service [service_name]
```

I know I can do:

```
juju destroy-machine --force [machine_number]
```

But this can't easily be automated with a script, as the script doesn't know the number of the machine.

Is there a way either to:

- have `destroy-service` also take the machine with it, or
- get the machine number of my `[service_name]` with a simple bash command, to pass to `destroy-machine`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the above is the desired behaviour for Juju. the reasoning behind this is that a user may wish to remove a service, but there may still be value in data that is stored on the machine after the service is removed (e.g. log files etc). Additionally, in deployments where several services are deployed to the same machine (e.g. using containers), removing the machine would be... unfortunate. So the best way to overcome this problem is by scripting.

```
juju status [service_name]
```

will return the status for a single service, so you could use this as a basis for a short script.

Comment: This is more of a justification than an answer. In any case, surely we can trust the administrator to know whether a machine can be safely destroyed or not? I agree destroying the machine shouldn't be the default, but to add a `--destroy-machine` flag to `destroy-service` wouldn't harm anyone? Currently there is no way to destroy a machine by the name of a service, which is what I really want: `juju destroy-machine-for-service [my_service]`

Comment: I was just trying to explain why the software doesn't do what you wanted :)

If you think an additional parameter would be useful, you can always file a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/

Comment: @Robin This is a bug in Juju, since we can't handle storage the idea was to not toss away data. Here's a bug to make it destroy the machine the default, or at a bare minimum add a flag: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1299034

Comment: @JorgeCastro thanks that's exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. Would you like to write this up as an answer to this question or shall I?

Comment: Feel free to write it up, though maybe focus on some ideas for workarounds while we sort it in juju itself.